# IntelliJ Add a Scala subproject in a nested directory

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a repo with multiple sub-projects, that looks like this:

```
my-project
├── .idea
├── backend
│   │── build.sbt 
│   │── src
│   └── ... other Scala subproject files
├── client
│   │── package.json
│   │── webpack.config.js
│   └── ... other JS subproject files
├── worker
│   └── ... other Python subproject files
├── Makefile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, I want to have the whole repo opened in the same window, import `./backend` as a "subproject", and be able to install all sbt dependencies. How can I do that?

If I open `./backend` as a separate project, IntelliJ imports all correctly, defines a ton of libraries and modules from the `build.sbt` file, and also re-imports them if I change `build.sbt`.

But for the shared project it won't import anything. If I manually import an sbt project from `./backend` in the `Project Structure -> Modules`, it switches to the root dir anyway and doesn't import libraries. I can get syntax highlighting and autocompletion for the main library and my own files, but the packages from `build.sbt` are missing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it switches to the root dir"? Note that currently using sbt shell for build/import won't work if the sbt project root is not the same as the IntelliJ project root, but with the sbt shell option disabled it should work when you import as module.

Comment: Issue is old but still there. I have created a ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-350390/IntelliJ-IDEA-does-not-load-sbt-project-in-nested-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy root sbt project in the root folder, creating a separate `build.sbt` there and using `backend` as a subproject:

`lazy val backend = (project in file("backend"))`